# How to convert particular column values to one row based on other column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have data  like below.

```
col1    col2
23      101
23      102
24      101
25      102
25      103
```

I want to pivot col2 based on col1. Desired output is like below.

```
col1   pro_1  pro_2   pro_3
23     101    102     NA
24     101    NA      NA
25     NA     102     103
```

Tried like below:

```
data.pivot(data,columns=['col_1'],values=['col_2'])
```

I got an error like below:

```
ValueError: The name col_1 occurs multiple times, use a level number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide information on the `columns` you want to put the values in `'col2'` into. I think this is what you want:

```
mapping = {101: 'pro1', 102: 'pro2', 103: 'pro3'}
df['cols'] = df.col2.map(mapping)
df.pivot(index='col1', values='col2', columns='cols')
```

Edit: You can create the mapping automatically like so:

```
df['cols'] = 'pro' + df.col2.astype(str)
```

Edi2: You can check if your data has duplicate rows like so:

```
df.duplicated()
```

If you simply want to get rid of these you can do

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated()].pivot(index='col1', values='col2', columns='cols')
```

Comment: I have provided sample of data above. But i Have 1892 unique values.I can not do mapping manually for all values.

Comment: @Magie I have edited my answer. You could create a mapping like so `df['cols'] = 'pro' + df.col2.astype(str)`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with updated answer getting ```ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape``` .

Comment: @Magie It works with the sample data you have provided. Quite possibly your full data set has multiple rows with identical 'col1' and 'col2' values. You can replicate this by doing `df2 = df.append(df.loc[0])` and then `df2.pivot(index='col1', values='col2', columns='cols')`. What would you like to do with these duplicate rows?

Comment: I have dropped duplicates and tried it again but i am getting same error.

Comment: @Magie Unfortunately, it's hard to tell what's going on without seeing your full dataset. What is the output of `df.duplicated().any()`?

Comment: ```data.duplicated().any() Out[5]: False```

Comment: Strange,not having duplicates in the data but error is related to duplicates. Is there any method to solve?

Comment: @Magie Great, what was this issue? Let me know if above answer needs updating or feel free to accept it.

Comment: For some reason It is not showed duplicates in the data before. I have restarted the kernel and dropped duplicates.Then it worked.